# Java: silly newbie issue about path used in import statement

Tags: java

I'm working through the example here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html

In my file, I've got:

```
package com.mycompanyname.mydirectory;

import com.mycompanyname.OneOfMyClasses;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
...

 public class MyClass {
     ...
 }
```

Everything is working fine. What I don't understand is that since I just copied the import statement directly from the link above for the iText portion -- why does `com.itextpdf.text.Document` work?

I mean, if I look in directory `com.mycompanyname` I can see `OneOfMyClasses.java` there.

But in the `com` directly, there is no `itextpdf` directory (although maybe my user doesn't have permission to see it(?)).

Hoping someone can help me understand what I'm missing here. Doesn't the import point to a specific directory that I should be able to see the class? Is there a different `com` directory somewhere that iText is using, and `com.itextpdf.text` points to there? (if so, where's the directory located)?

I installed the jar file for iText in the `lib` folder as per usual, and made sure it was included in the classpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those classes are inside a JAR file that is added to the classpath:

> Create a new Java project "de.vogella.itext.write" with the package "de.vogella.itext.write". Create a folder "lib" and put the *iText library (jar file)* into this folder. *Add the jar to your classpath*.

import statements will look inside whatever directory trees are in the classpath, which includes the current directory at compilation time (tipically the src/ directory in your project) as well as any directory specified through environment variable or JVM startup parameter. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) about the classpath.

**EDIT**

You do need the imports whenever you use classes across packages. Every public class/interface you define is in a package. If whatever you are referencing belongs to another package, you need to import it.

JARs are zip files that contain directories and files inside. It's the same as plain directories and files, only packed.

Comment: Yes, I did all that. Is my import statement even needed then, or is there a more logical way to write it?

Comment: @ggkmath, unless your class is in the same package as the class it uses then you must use the import statement.  But you can use a wildcard if you import lots from the same package, e.g. `import com.itextpdf.text.*;`

Comment: @ggkmath wildcard imports are easy to use but also to misuse, so they are discouraged (they may result in unintentional cross-package name conflicts which may or may not be detected by the compiler)

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the iText dependency (jar) you added in an earlier step.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily - you could also import from libraries, etc.

In fact, Java will try to search through the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). Here is some helpful [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html).

Comment: OK, assuming Java found it in the classpath, which it should, can I clean up the code somehow as not to mislead myself?

Comment: Java will always need that line to find the class, so there's really not much you could do. If you are using eclipse, then any unused import should give you a warning, which might help you cleanup the code.

Answer (score 1):

That class is most probably imported in a `JAR` library. Inside such JAR file, the class files are kept in exact package/folder structure as you use when importing them.

Comment: Then, is my import statement for `com.itextpdf.text.Document` redundant or unnecessary? How to clean it up so it's not confusing?

Comment: @ggkmath, inside such JAR file, the classes will be present to follow the same directory structure. No it is not a redundancy.

Comment: OK, I think I see now. The `com.itextpdf.text` refers to the directory structure in the jar file and so there's nothing I can do to change it, and even more important, it is required to be included as such. Right?

Comment: @ggkmath, Exactly, You got it.